# How to have completed form emailed to me

Tags: forms, paypal

I have a form with multiple text inputs, radio inputs, checkboxes and a file input ([jsfiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/uvh0tpbu/1/)):

```
  <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="form">
    <div id="contact">Contact Info
      <br><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name*" required>
      <br><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name*" required>
      <br><input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company">
      <br><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" required>
    </div><br>

    <div id="Specifics">Specifics
      <div id="location">Location
        <br><input type="radio" name="pages" id="page1" value="2" required><label for="page1"> /page1</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="pages" id="page2" value="1.5"><label for="page2"> /page2</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="pages" id="page3" value="1.5"><label for="page3"> /page3</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="pages" id="page4" value="1.5"><label for="page4"> /page4</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="pages" id="page5" value="1"><label for="page5"> /page5</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="pages" id="page6" value="1"><label for="page6"> /page6</label>
      </div><br>

      <div id="topbtm">Top or Bottom?
        <br><input type="radio" name="location" id="tb_top" required><label for="tb_top">Top</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="location" id="tb_btm"><label for="tb_btm">Bottom</label>
      </div><br>

      <div id="selection">Selection
        <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s1" value="4"><span>1</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s2" value="4"><span>2</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s3" value="4"><span>3</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s4" value="4"><span>4</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s5" value="4"><span>5</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s6" value="4"><span>6</span></label>
        <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s7" value="4"><span>7</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s8" value="4"><span>8</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s9" value="4"><span>9</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s10" value="4"><span>10</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s11" value="4"><span>11</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="s12" value="4"><span>12</span></label>
      </div><br>

      <div id="weeks">Weeks
        <br><select required><option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option><option value="7">1 week</option><option value="14">2 weeks</option><option value="21">3 weeks</option><option value="28">4 weeks</option></select>
      </div>
    </div><br>

    <div id="info">Info
      <br><input type="file" name="image" value="image" accept="image/jpg" required>
      <br><input type="url" name="url" placeholder="Linked Website (URL)" required>
      <br><input type="text" name="color" placeholder="Background Color" required>
      <br><input type="text" name="hovertext" placeholder="Hover Text">
    </div><br>

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="(myemail)" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="total" value=""/>
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
  </form>
```

How can I have the input **ID's**, **not values** emailed to me upon a certain action?

I don't know a way to submit this form when a payment is successfully *completed* (please let me know if this is possible), so another idea I had was to have PayPal redirect to a "success" page when the payment was successful, and submit the form when that "success" page is reached. So **1)** how can I have this form be submitted when that page is reached and
**2)** how can I only receive the input *ID*'s instead of the values?

Comment: What is the significance of the PHP tag? Does your app use PHP on the backend? If so, are you familiar with the PHP `mail()` function?

Comment: No it does not use PHP, I put it because I am open to PHP answers. I am a newbie, I'm not familiar with that sorry

Comment: Am I correct that you're more or less following this article? - https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside

Comment: No, I haven't :( All I have is a buy now button and a jQuery script that calculates the price, hence the values in some of the inputs. No third party thing. Only because I wouldn't know how to set it up the same way with all those PayPal variables

Comment: Well in a nutshell, I can tell you that you're going to need some sort of server-side code to handle emailing you any data. PHP is certainly an option - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - I've used it, it works, but you need a server to send it from. You could also use the server-side to do the other things that you need to - submit the Paypal info, confirm that it was processed successfully, and then handle other form data... to get the ids of the submitted fields, you should probably just use a hidden form field to hold that value, I don't think there's a way to get it directly.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand well .But if you want to get the id of The last record inserted in database , you can use:

```
mysqli_insert_id($connection_value)
```

and you can use mail() to send an email !!!.

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);
```

And if you just want to send your elements id's , There are several ways to do that ! On is to make hidden inputs and pass their values to your page then send them use email ! the secound way that I can suggest you is to use javascript , and make an ajax file that gets you'r form id's then send them to your mail !

---

Have a good day ! Apr <3

Comment: I think that the OP is looking to get the ids of the HTML input fields. I think...

Comment: if you explain me more , i can help you !

Comment: @skwidbreth Me too . but if he explain it exactly , I post another comment to help him. !!!

Comment: Yeah to clarify, I need to get the IDs as that is the information I as the seller need to know, because the _values_ are just the price. So in the div #selection, I need to be emailed "s1", "s2" or whatever the user selects instead of the value "4". Because otherwise I would just receive a fom with a bunch of 4's and not know what the user actually selected.